# Is there a way to run test scripts one after another using puppeteer as i don't want each js file to be big

Tags: jest-puppeteer

I've 2 test files, test1.js and test2.js. I want to run them in sequence, test 1 then run test2. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you came up with a different solution, please share it  otherwise, if it was helpful, accept my answer. Both could be useful to other users 

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`runInBand` option of Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#runinband) (`runInBand` doesn't care about the order of the tests, obviously. In case you need to preserve the order of the tests, you're probably doing them wrong).